# Виртуальность и стандартные библиотеки

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.
Предыстория: занимаюсь uefi, в нем использую c++ в sdk(edk2). Этот самый edk2 не позволяет использовать библиотеки, поставляемые вместе с компилятором.

Собственно вопрос: Мне нужно использовать полиморфизм, но при создании класса с виртуальной функцией получаю ошибку undefined reference to `vtable for **cxxabiv1::**class_type_info'

Значит ли это, что механизм виртуальности использует стандартные библиотеки, в частности cxxabi, и можно ли этого избежать как-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор какой? Отключите ABI и RTTI через ключи командной строки. Думаю, поможет.

**UPD:** окончательно помогли ключи `-fno-rtti` и `-fno-exceptions`

Comment: Компилятор gcc, пока что не смог найти ключей для отключения, продолжу поиск

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, отключение RTTI помогло!

Comment: Т.е. Вы использовали ключ `-fno-rtti`?

Comment: Да, и еще -fno-exceptions на всякий случай.

Comment: ОК. Я вас понял.